# Uploading an image to Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I need to upload a bitmap to Amazon S3. Below is the code I have so far, built after going through the docs and sample code.

```
public class AmazonS3Test {

private static final String TAG = "MyApp.AmazonS3Stuff";
private static AmazonS3 mS3 = null;
private static final String mS3BucketName = "bucketname";
private static BasicAWSCredentials mCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(".....", "....");

private static void uploadImageToAmazonS3(String key, File file) {
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(mS3BucketName, key, file);
    try {
        PutObjectResult result = getS3Instance().putObject(request);
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Amazon exception uploading the image to Amazon S3 " + key + " " + mS3BucketName, e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception uploading the image to Amazon S3 " + key + " " + mS3BucketName, e);
    }
    // TODO Handle result
}

private static AmazonS3 getS3Instance() {
    if (mS3 == null) {
        mS3 = new AmazonS3Client(mCredentials);    // <---- Exception here
    }
    return mS3;
}
```

}

Stack trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.i.a
    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.addapps.taxiapp.utils.Utils.getS3Instance(AmazonS3Test.java)
```

I've little idea what that exception means, or why I cannot get an instance of AmazonS3.

I'm really struggling with S3, so if anyone can point me to any good resources I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception was caused by my not having all the required AWS libraries in the project. AWS has a lot of libraries in different forms, and although not clear which are required, it won't work until the right ones are present.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the Amazon Web Service Client is using Apache commons HttpClient. From the stacktrace, it appears as if you have a library conflict. Check to see if you are using HttpClient somewhere else in your project. Most likely, you are using a different version than the Amazon Web Service Client is expecting.